# How to get json results prior to my custom schema in java/jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I a coming to an problem where I am trying to result my json format properly. So, I got the first part of my custom schema, but I need some help to fix the second part which is the array list of hours,weekly, annual to list values as array and I am stuck to solve this issue. can anyone help me solve this. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create list from steps and use `writeObjectField` method to serialise this list. Below you can find example implementation:

```
class JobSerializer extends StdSerializer<Salary> {

    public JobSerializer() {
        this(Salary.class);
    }

    public JobSerializer(Class<Salary> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Salary value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("id", value.jobClassCd + value.payGrade + value.jobGroup);
        jgen.writeStringField("label", value.jobClassTitle + "( " + value.jobClassCd + value.payGrade + ") " + value.jobGroup);

        jgen.writeStringField("pay_grade_description_link", "payGrade");
        jgen.writeStringField("job_type", value.sectionToDisplay);
        jgen.writeStringField("mou", value.mou);
        jgen.writeStringField("mou_description", value.mouDescription);
        jgen.writeStringField("special_notes", value.specialNotes);
        jgen.writeStringField("salary_range_min_step_message", value.salaryRangeMinStepMessage);

        List<String> jobs = Arrays.asList(value.step1, value.step2, value.step3, value.step4, value.step5, value.step6, value.step7,
                value.step8, value.step9, value.step10, value.step11, value.step12, value.step13, value.step14,
                value.step15, value.step16, value.step17, value.step18, value.step19, value.step20);
        jgen.writeObjectField(value.rateType, jobs);

        jgen.writeEndObject();

    }
}
```

Also, you can remove `@JsonSerialize` from all properties in `Salary` class. It is not required and can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also, you know why I am getting 3 jobs printed instead one big json object? as shown an example on schema.

Comment: @VeeA, I do not understand what do you mean. Could you update question with how you serialise `Salary` objects and result `JSON`?

Comment: updated question with my json results. I am getting 3 objects instead one. please see my custom schema.

Comment: @VeeA, it looks like you have created 3 `Salary` instances with different `rateType` fields. It is not related with `Jackson`, rather you need to fix your code.

Comment: In my `Salary` class or in my controllers?

Comment: @VeeA, looks like in controller. Try to debug your code.

Comment: @VeeA, no problem. I'm glad I could help. In case my answer was helpful, please, accept and upvote. Take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hey @Michal can I post my controller class for me to help me this 3 `Salary` instance?

Comment: @VeeA, just create a new question and describe your new problem because it looks like an another problem.